# Knockout kendo window resize event

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid within a kendo window, both bound with knockout and I would like to synchronize their sizes.

Currently the window can be resized but the contained grid only syncs on width, not height.

I've tried adding a resize listener to the binding:

```
data-bind="kendoWindow: { resize: resizeHandler}"
```

I've tried adding a binding onto the kendo window like this:

```
$("#windowId").data("kendoWindow").bind("resize", function () { console.log("resize") });
```

I've looked at the knockout kendo javascript and found that the resize event was not handled so I tried to add it but without effect:

```
createBinding({
    name: "kendoWindow",
    events: {
        open: {
        writeTo: ISOPEN,
        value: true
    },
    close: {
        writeTo: ISOPEN,
        value: false
    },
        resize: SIZE
    },
    watch: {
        content: CONTENT,
        title: TITLE,
        isOpen: [OPEN, CLOSE]
    },
    async: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an existing resize handler in my code. Maybe this was eating the resize event possibly.

```
if (widget) {
  widget.resize = function() {
      var newWindowHeight = self.queryTableWindow().element.height();
      var newWindowWidth = self.queryTableWindow().element.width();

      self.queryTableWindowHeight(newWindowHeight);
      self.queryTableWindowWidth(newWindowWidth);
  }
}
```

Could someone close this? I don't think I have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
createBinding({
    name: "kendoWindow",
    events: {
        open: {
            writeTo: ISOPEN,
            value: true
        },
        close: {
            writeTo: ISOPEN,
            value: false
        },
        resize: function (options, event) {
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(options.width)) {
                options.width(event.sender.wrapper.width());
            }
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(options.height)) {
                options.height(event.sender.wrapper.height());
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        content: CONTENT,
        title: TITLE,
        isOpen: [OPEN, CLOSE],
        width: WIDTH,
        height: HEIGHT
    },
    async: true
});
```